# Why does my Canon printer cut off margin on one side of double sided pages?

Tags: printing, pdf, canon

When I try and print PDFs on Ubuntu 17.10 with my Canon MG5750 the second side of every double sided page cuts off the first inch of content.

This also occurred in 16.04 and happens with all PDF viewers I have tested (firefox's native, okular, and the default PDF viewer that comes with Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

If you install the drivers that Canon supply for this printer?
If you go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100690202.html and click to download and SAVE what will be cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb.tar.gz

If you open a terminal; copy each command below; line by line; and paste into the terminal and hit the ENTER key after each paste

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb
```

the final command runs the install script; please watch the terminal as it will ask some questions

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

we hope this helps